# Viewcontroller and performwithsegue problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

[image]I have a VC and has a button on the top nav bar, which i use

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SetUptoMain" sender:self];`

to send to another VC. All ok so far - The segue is setup to use `'Push'` , If I set it to modal it doesn't work.

[image]

You can see the segue coming from the SetupVC to View Controller. To the left is a NAV controller. 
The problem is that the pink cog does not show at all when i use [performSegueWithIndentifier. Is it because the segue needs to be connected to the nav controller ?

Comment: please show the whole storyboard image

Comment: Navigation Controller -ViewController (Relationship segues,dont need to set push)